# Oracle Sql Developer format sql

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using the latest Oracle Sql Developer application and the feature to Format SQL. Below is the way the formatter formats the Substr function. It puts on multiple lines. Is there a setting to not do this and compress into one line?

```
, SUBSTR(
TEST_1, 1, 2
)                  Test1
```

Desired:

```
, SUBSTR(TEST_1, 1, 2) Test1
```

Comment: have you and tried the (incredible number of) settings for formatting?